# How to delete selected node from XML in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2010, xmlnode

I am New To C# I have problem...
I want to delete `selected node` from My `XMl` File
Here I just tried with this code but I didn't get please can any one help in that

```
private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    xdoc.Load(strFilename);
    string Xpath = string.Format("root/{0}/{1}",_strProCat,_strProdType);
    xdoc.SelectSingleNode(Xpath).RemoveAll();

    xdoc.Save(strFilename);
    MessageBox.Show("Deleted Successfully");
}
```

Here My Xml File

```
<root>
  <product category="Soaps">
   <product type="Washing">
     <product name="Rin">
      <Id>100</Id>
      <AvailProducts>30</AvailProducts>
      <Cost>20.00</Cost>
   </product>
  <product name="Tide">
    <Id>101</Id>
    <AvailProducts>30</AvailProducts>
    <Cost>15.00</Cost>
  </product>
 </product>
</product>
</root>
```

Just I want to delete Node which product `name="Tide"`

Comment: Which type is `xdoc` and what are the values of `_strProCat` and `_strProdType`?

Comment: can you please tell me that How you add **ID** in XML file ? with auto +1 with new record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simple use the below code:

```
private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var xDoc = XDocument.Load(strFilename);

    foreach (var elem in xDoc.Document.Descendants("product"))
    {
        foreach (var attr in elem.Attributes("name"))
        {
            if (attr.Value.Equals("Tide"))
                elem.RemoveAll();
        }
    }

    xDoc.Save(destinationFilename);
    MessageBox.Show("Deleted Successfully");
}
```

Happy Coding...

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do it:

```
xdoc.Elements("product").Where(x=> x.Element("name").Value == "Tide").FirstOrDefault().Remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want `XPath` with `XmlDocument` then following is the way to do it..

```
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.Load(strFilename);
string Xpath = string.Format("root/product[@category='{0}']/product[@type='{1}']/product[@name='{2}']", "Soaps", "Washing", "Tide");
xdoc.SelectSingleNode(Xpath).RemoveAll();
xdoc.Save(strFilename);
```

**Update**

As per your Requirement `To Remove the empty node`, try following code to remove empty node as

```
XmlNodeList emptyElements = xdoc.SelectNodes(@"//*[not(node())]");
for (int i = emptyElements.Count - 1; i > -1; i--)
{
     XmlNode nodeToBeRemoved = emptyElements[i];
     nodeToBeRemoved.ParentNode.RemoveChild(nodeToBeRemoved);
}
```

*Now your final full flesh code will look like as*

```
string Xpath = string.Format("root/product[@category='{0}']/product[@type='{1}']/product[@name='{2}']", "Soaps", "Washing", "Tide");                      
xdoc.SelectSingleNode(Xpath).RemoveAll();
XmlNodeList emptyElements = xdoc.SelectNodes(@"//*[not(node())]");

for (int i = emptyElements.Count - 1; i > -1; i--)
{
      XmlNode nodeToBeRemoved = emptyElements[i];
      nodeToBeRemoved.ParentNode.RemoveChild(nodeToBeRemoved);
}
xdoc.Save(strFilename);
```

Comment: It will work properly But In this code I have troubled one problem

Comment: <product name="Rin">
           <Id>100</Id>
           <AvailProducts>30</AvailProducts>
           <Cost>20.00</Cost>
        </product> 
after deleting <product></product> This attributes are remains What i want is Delete Those node s also please what should I do?